# How come Mokarin's mom is so good with guns?

Tags: sabagebu

In multiple episodes of *Sabagebu!*, Mokarin's mom handles her gun exceptionally well and she's sort of badass too (Episode 7).

[image: Mokarin's mom]

But how come? Was she part of her own Survival Club? Or, has she had some professional experience with guns? Was this ever revealed in the anime or manga?

Note: spoiler is acceptable.

Comment: According to [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%95%E3%81%B0%E3%81%92%E3%81%B6%E3%81%A3!#%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E4%BB%96%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%A9%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC), Kazue Sonokawa's gun handling is anime exclusive. In the original manga, while she's shown of her high-level physical skill, she's never shown using a gun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Momoka's skill is possibly hereditary. Kazue Sonokawa (her mother) possibly has a natural affinity with weapons just as Momoka does. She's possibly seen a bit of action when she was younger too and has the lessons of experience as an advantage.

Another contributing factor is that Kazue is an adult. Adults in Japan are allowed weild more powerful weapons than juveniles' airsoft guns. Adolescents can only use guns which are limited to a kinetic energy of 0.135 Joules. However, adults can use guns with 1 Joule - which could be why her bullets seemingly shot through the floor and also gave her an advantage over Momoka

[Reference.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_issues_in_airsoft#Japan)

(It was probably just the mangaka's decision though)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't exactly look into considering it was a one-off moment expressed comedically. So in all honesty, as BADASS as that paints her (and I'm all on board for more badass moms in media in general), I still firmly believe it's just for laughs that'll probably be left forgotten.

I could be wrong though, guess we'll see if the show actually goes to address it.

Comment: Doesn't she say something like "A mother's battlefield is the home"? Which would imply that's considered standard housewife knowledge in-universe. I wouldn't go looking for logic in Sabagebu though.